# How to auto adjust margin between two vertical buttons based on their visibilities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have 2 buttons that are aligned vertically in Android XML layout. There is a 16dp space between the two.

I would like that space to toggle based on both buttons' visibilities.

Like this when both are visible (16dp margin between them):

[image]

Like this when button 1 is gone (no margins and button 2 shifts up):

[image]

Like this when button 2 is gone (no margin below button 1 now):

[image]

I tried LinearLayout, ConstraintLayout with vertical chain but didn't find any solution.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Take a look at [gone margins](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#GoneMargin). I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ConstraintLayout` you can achieve what you want with the `layout_goneMarginXXX` attributes.

You can read more about it in the [`ConstraintLayout doc`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#GoneMargin)

For your problem all you have to do is set:

```xml
...
layout_goneMarginBottom="0dp"
...
```